Excel. Подсчет уникальных значений
Подскажите пожалуйста формулу подсчета уникальных значений в каждом секторе, за исключением тех, которые были посчитаны в предыдущем секторе. Для первого сектора нет проблем посчитать - это будут все значения этого сектора. А вот с остальными не понятно.


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

Решение:

Остортировать массив по секторам (t).
Для каждого уникального имени выбрать из (1) первый встречающийся сектор (v).
Из (2) подсчитать количество упоминаний каждого сектора.


Формула:
D2=LET(t;SORT(A2:B11;2);
    v;VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(DROP(t;;-1));t;2;FALSE);
    u;UNIQUE(v);
    HSTACK(u;MAP(u;LAMBDA(x;COUNT(IF(v=x;1;""))))
    )
)


Прошу прощения, а в вашем примере какие значения принимают (t), (v), (n), (x)? Я конечно попробовал методом подбора, но ничего не вышло

Если интересны значения t и v, то выведите их отдельно, укоротив формулу, например: t это SORT(A2:B11;2), а v - LET(t;SORT(A2:B11;2);VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(DROP(t;;-1));t;2;FALSE)). x - это итератор по v: LET(t;SORT(A2:B11;2);v;VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(DROP(t;;-1));t;2;FALSE);UNIQUE(v)).

P. S. x - это итератор по UNIQUE(v): LET(t;SORT(A2:B11;2);v;VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(DROP(t;;-1));t;2;FALSE);UNIQUE(v)).

С помощью диалогового окна Расширенный фильтр можно извлечь уникальные значения из столбца данных и вставить их в новое местоположение. Затем с помощью функции ЧСТРОК можно подсчитать количество элементов в новом диапазоне.

Выделите диапазон ячеек или убедитесь, что активная ячейка находится в таблице.
Убедитесь в том, что диапазон ячеек содержит заголовок столбца.

На вкладке Данные в группе Фильтр & сортировки выберите Дополнительно.
Появится диалоговое окно Расширенный фильтр.

Выберите Копировать в другое расположение.

В поле Копировать введите ссылку на ячейку.
Кроме того, выберите Свернуть диалоговое окно кнопки , чтобы временно скрыть диалоговое окно, выделите ячейку на листе и нажмите кнопку Развернуть диалоговое окно кнопки.

Установите флажок Только уникальные записи и нажмите кнопку ОК.
Уникальные значения из выделенного диапазона будут скопированы в новое место, начиная с ячейки, указанной в поле Копировать.

В пустой ячейке под последней ячейкой диапазона введите функцию ЧСТРОК. Используйте диапазон скопированных уникальных значений в качестве аргумента, исключив заголовок столбца. Например, если уникальные значения содержатся в диапазоне B2:B45, введите =ЧСТРОК(B2:B45).


